# a question about calculatewinner in Tictactoe Tutorial for React

Tags: reactjs

so this is the part in the Tutorial

```
function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
```

I tried to interpret this code, and I understood almost all - except for

```
squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b]
```

why is there 'squares[a]' for the first condition?
the code works even without it, and according to syllogism it should make sense only with the other two conditions.

is it just to make sure that the code works without an exception?

Comment: Ask yourself: What if `squares[a]` contained no value (`null`)? So this is a straight line of three nulls. Would the game be over?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably there to ensure that the winning line is actually populated with an X or an O. For example, in the following game in progress:

```
X# #O
#####
 #X#
#####
 # #
```

when no one's played on the 3rd line yet, you wouldn't want the 3-in-a-row of empty spaces on the 3rd line to count as a win.

Presumably, the `squares` array contains falsey values when no one's played on a square yet - and Xs or Os are associated with something truthy, like 1 and 2 or something like that. So testing `squares[a]` first will exclude the 3-in-a-row of empty spaces from counting as a win.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no squares [a]&&judgment, the game will continue. Even if the last two columns are satisfied, you still need to click the first column to determine who is the winner (according to the order in the array). As follows:

1. null O X
2. null  O X
3. null  O X

Click one of the first columns to end the game (the winner is determined according to the value sequence of the array).As follows:
winner:O

1. X    O X
2. null  O X
3. null  O X